# Sench Touch MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, sencha-touch

I am pretty new to MVC and I have implemented it in my Sencha touch app. My question is what is the advantage of implementing the Sencha Touch controller Ext.Controller and dispatching to it over using just regular js functions instead? In my experience you can do the same with both but Ext.Controller requires a bit more code to do.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168561/why-should-i-use-ext-dispatch-rather-than-calling-controller-code-directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168561/why-should-i-use-ext-dispatch-rather-than-calling-controller-code-directly) question answered it for me, kindly provide by Luis. As for as I can tell you can use the dispatch and the controller to load only the code needed instead of all at once on page load as well as better control on event handling.

Answer (score 1):

find this below link, you will get clear step by step approach to MVC using sencha touch

[sencha-touch-mvc-application-from-scratch](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/mobile-development/creating-a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-from-scratch-part-1/)